# Jasper reports font error

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using Jasper Reports 5.2.0 and Spring MVC with Maven.

I have done reports using JasperViewer, but suddenly I am getting this error that can't be resolved:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font '
        net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.ttf
        net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.svg
        net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.eot
        net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.woff
    ' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the jar extra placed jars in your lib folder it works properly 
or use same version jar file in maven dependency and webroot ->lib folder or in class path

Comment: Uh? This is a missing font problem, see http://javaskeleton.blogspot.sg/2010/12/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by.html

Answer (score 3):

For me, in one instance, the problem was with the jasperreports version as I had more that one jasperreports jar in my classpath.

My reports were compiled with jasperreports-5.6.0 and in my classpath jasperreports-4.1.1.jar was also included and accidentally jasperreports-4.1.1.jar was "up" in the Build class path order.

Actually, my eclipse project had jasperreports-5.6.0 as a library jar and this project had another project as "Required projects in the build path" that contained the old version of jasperreports.

I moved the jasperreports-5.6.0 to "Up in the build classpath order" than the old version, and the problem got resolved.

Again, later I removed the project dependency and got the problem resolved as well.

So check, whether you have more than one jasperreports library  anyhow; if so, remove the unnecessary duplicate jar.

Comment: This is not how you answer here on SO, please include relevant part of your answer here from the link.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem +1. I had accidentally jasperreports 5.2.0 and 5.5.1 in my WEB-INF/lib folder. The result was crazy exceptions like: JRFontNotFoundException: Font ' net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.ttf and Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser. But I agree with 4dgaurav

Comment: Edited the answer as per comments from 4dgaurav.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is one of the fonts you used in Jasper Reports not installed in the system. The solution is to install all missing fonts. Another alternative is to use only the fonts "Serif" and "San-Serif" which eliminates the need of installing fonts seperately and would even work when the code is moved accross different servers.

Comment: thank u jeevan ..but i have run the reports successfully using verdana..font suddenly it behaves like that

Comment: Have u made any changes to java version or deploy code in another other machine prior to the one where you ran the reports successfully

Comment: See http://javaskeleton.blogspot.sg/2010/12/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by.html